# Getting Haskell record fields based on their type

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I would like to define a typeclass for accessing specific fields in records based on their type. In this toy example, we have a Failable (that's just an Either) that can be present in different records and wrapping different types. I'm interested if it would be possible to define a single function *failableFrom* and let the compiler select the correct instance based on the context.

```
type Money  = Double
type Name   = String
type ErrMsg = String

class HasFailable a b where
  failableFrom :: a -> Either ErrMsg b

data SomeRecord = SomeRecord (Either ErrMsg Name) (Either ErrMsg Money)

instance HasFailable SomeRecord Name where
  failableFrom (SomeRecord name _) = name

instance HasFailable SomeRecord Money where
  failableFrom (SomeRecord _ money) = money

data SomeOtherRecord = SomeOtherRecord (Either ErrMsg Name)

instance HasFailable SomeOtherRecord Name where
  failableFrom (SomeOtherRecord name) = name

data SomeOtherOtherRecord = SomeOtherOtherRecord (Either ErrMsg Money)

instance HasFailable SomeOtherOtherRecord Money where
  failableFrom (SomeOtherOtherRecord money) = money



-- some record
record = SomeRecord (Right "John") (Right 200.0)

-- let the compiler decide what failableFrom function to use
moreMoney = fmap (\money -> money + 200.0) $ failableFrom record
```

I'm asking this mainly out of curiosity about what's possible in Haskell.

Comment: That code works if you change the last `instance HasFailable SomeOtherOtherRecord Name` to `instance HasFailable SomeOtherOtherRecord Money` and nail down the type of `moreMoney` (e.g. by doing `money + 200 :: Money`).

Comment: `SomeRecord`, `SomeOtherRecord` and `SomeOtherOtherRecord` can all be types I think. I think it is way too difficult what you are doing.

Comment: @melpomene Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a typeclass for accessing specific fields in records based on their
>   type

Something like this can be accomplished using [generic programming](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generics), a technique for inspecting the structure of data types and defining functions that work across diverse data types according to the structure of each.

To use generic programming, one must enable the [`DeriveGeneric`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=derivegeneric#extension-DeriveGeneric) extension and import the [`GHC.Generics`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) module.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics

type Money  = Double
type Name   = String
type ErrMsg = String

data SomeRecord = SomeRecord (Either ErrMsg Name) (Either ErrMsg Money) deriving (Generic)
```

Writing the generics-based "typed accessor" function by ourselves would be complicated. Fortunately, that functionality is already implemented in the [`Data.Generics.Product.Typed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Generics-Product-Typed.html) module of the [generic-lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens) package. That module provides the [`typed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-Generics-Product-Typed.html#v:typed) lens that lets us target fields in a record by their (unique) type.

(A *lens* is a value that packs together a getter and a setter for a record field. The [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package contains the main definitions and functions for working with them, in particular the [`view`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:view) function for getting a field's value.)

```
import Control.Lens (view)
import Data.Generics.Product.Typed (typed)

moreMoney :: Either ErrMsg Money
moreMoney = fmap (\money -> money + 200.0) $ view typed record
```

Here the compiler deduced we wanted the `Money` field because of the type signature. But we could have also used an explicit [type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=typeapplications#extension-TypeApplications):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

moreMoney' = fmap (\money -> money + 200.0) $ view (typed @(Either _ Money)) record
```

Comment: Using typeclasses also allows argument constraints in functions. Would something similar be possible here, i.e. have a function that takes anything containing an Either ErrMsg Money?

Comment: @PetrasPurlys Yes, using the `HasType` typeclass from `Data.Generics.Product.Typed`. The `typed` lens is actually a method of `HasType`.